# Weird issue in input box field with events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am running to an issue that `input box` field with `window.getSelection method`.

For some reason, I can't type anything in the `input box` if I add

```
window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
```

in my codes.

My codes:

```
//register a mouseup event to the whole page so wherever user releases mouse it trigger mouseUP function

//body -> whole html page
addEvent(body, 'onmouseup', mouseUp);

function mouseUp(){
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
}
```

I have several `input boxes` on the page and if I add

```
window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
```

the cursor won't even appear and I can't type anything.

Can anyone give me a hint for this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: did my answer help you? please mark the question as answered, otherwise please post more details about your problem. thank you

Answer (score 0):

The reason is your onmousup event, which will remove the cursor as soon as you click into the input field. add those lines to the beginning of your mouseUp function to prevent removeAllRanges be fired.

```
var x = window.getSelection();
if( x == '' && e.target == '[object HTMLInputElement]' ){
       return true;
}
```

For a full working example see: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/klickagent/pa5Sk/2/)